# What is the Destiny Merit?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

It was alluded to in The God-Machine Chronicle rules update:

> INFRASTRUCTURE
>   Description: The subject of this Condition is within the
>   sphere of influence of an angel.
>   ... In addition, characters with the Destiny
>   Merit are always subject to this Condition.

And in Chronicles of Darkness (2e corebook) the Fate Sense Numen also mentioned it:

> FATE SENSE
>   If using the Fate optional rule, the entity may taste the
>   Fate of a mortal being. The Numen costs 1 Essence, and is
>   contested by Resolve + Supernatural Tolerance. Characters
>   with the Destiny Merit may not contest this Numen. If the
>   entity succeeds, it knows the subject’s Fate and can discern
>   the presence of the Destiny Merit and its rating.

Is there any information from OPP on what the Destiny Merit is/was, if it was removed from earlier drafts in the editing process? Were there earlier drafts posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Destiny merit in **Mage: The Awakening 2e**, on page 100. It may be that it was originally intended to be printed in the core book, but it’s findable there.